# Powershell code to delete all files and folders in a directory except for last 2 days data and 2 folders

Tags: powershell

```
# set folder path
$dump_path = "C:\shares\*"
$Eliminate = @("*dump*", "*Perform")

# set min age of files
#$max_days = "-2" | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $del_date } 

# get the current date
#$curr_date = Get-Date

# determine how far back we go based on current date
#$del_date = $curr_date.AddDays($max_days)

# delete the files
Remove-Item -Recurse C:\shares\* -exclude $Eliminate
```

Comment: I was able to delete  all the files and folders except for two folders but I could not save the data of last five days. Need help.....

Comment: This has nothing to do with batchfiles.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like that:

```
Get-Childitem C:\shares -recurse | where {($_.creationtime -gt $del_date) -and ($_.name -notlike "*dump*" -and $_.name -notlike "*perform*")} | remove-item
```

I´m a bit rusty at the moment so someone might come up with a more elegant solution

Comment: Thanks Gill, it was close to the required output. As the command suggested by you is deleting the content present in the dump folder. Where as i want the content of dump folder to be present.